# Какой выбрать предлог: жарить в/на масле?

Tags: пунктуация, предлоги, словосочетания

Как правильно сказать: жарить в/на масле?

Answer (score 2):

**Жарить на масле** - сравнительно широкое понятие, с основным значением "*жарить с применением масла*" (часто подразумевается "сливочного" - в противопоставление растительным)". Важно то, что продукт при жарении частично впитывает в себя то, "на чём" он жарился, и от этого может зависеть его вкус - даже если это простая яичница-глазунья. Это относится не только к жарению: например, каша может быть (сварена) "**на молоке**" или "**на воде**" - с применением в процессе того или другого, что попадает и в конечный продукт. Торт тоже может быть *приготовлен на масле* или на маргарине. Поэтому данное понятие характеризует не только технологию, но и результат приготовления продукта (качество и состав).

**Жарить в масле** - конкретная характеристика *технологии* жарения (с большим количеством масла, с погружением в него или плаванием продукта в нём); при этом продукт будет *приготовлен **на** масле*.

Comment: Можете ли вы привести убедительный пример, когда продукт приготовлен по технологии "жарить в масле", а в предложении сказано, что его жарили (именно жарили, а не приготовили) на масле?

Comment: Уточню. Можно спросить, на каком масле лучше всего жарить картофель фри (с применением какого масла), потому, что здесь есть варианты. А если просто "жарить на масле" (с погружением), то вряд-ли какая-то альтернатива возможна (в маргарин не обычно погружают).

Comment: Не обязательно применять оба понятия к одному и тому же продукту (не всегда есть альтернативы тому, на чём жарят/готовят продукт), но примеры можно привести.

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=GhErDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT385&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=gukzEwaM-E&sig=ACfU3U0BclpDHe3EyCU3rPr8mOqPI_UsSA&w=1280

Чебуреки  - пирожки _на бараньем жире_

Известно, что готовят чебуреки всегда _погружёнными_ в то, на чём их готовят: традиционно - в растопленный бараний жир или (что проще и дешевле) в растительном масле. Соотвественно, готовят их _на масле_ или на бараньем жире.

Comment: С плавающим картофелем реже варьируют "то, на чём", тем не менее "картофель Сарладез" готовят _на утином жире_, и по правильной технологии (можно найти видео шеф-повара Лазерсона "конфи из утки"), его обильно заливают в кастрюле растопленным жиром (не перемешивают - масло его покрывает, и он жарится _в жире_) и в конце приготовления сливают жир через сито.

Comment: У вас описка (правильно: Салардез). С принципом применения "готовить на" я согласен, но примеров с "жарить на" не нашлось. Картофель готовят (а не жарят) на утином жире. "Чебуреки - пирожки на бараньем жире" — без глагола.

Comment: В оригинале - a la sarladaise, от города Sarlat (русск. Сарла). 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_confit

- Официант, на чём эту картошку жарили?
- На масле-с. Прямо в нём и плавала-с. Картофель фри, барин.

Comment: В оригинале - a la sarladaise, a в русском интернете - только Салардез. Нелогично, но факт.

Comment: Но это мелочи. А в общем Ваш ответ правильней, поэтому я мой ответ удаляю.